# Variable not accessible inside if statement. Language design?

Tags: go, syntax, scope, pug

So I'm working with an implementation of the Jade templating language for Go (see https://github.com/go-floki/jade) and I'm running into an interesting "feature" of the language. The code below works as expected, placing and `img` element for every headshot.

```
each $headshot in $object.Headshots
    img.img-circle.headshot(src=$headshot)
```

I then wanted to change it so on the sixth element the image source would be a preset image. However, when I run this code I get an error

```
each $headshot, index in $cause.Headshots
    if index == 6
        img.img-circle.headshot(src="/public/images/ellipse.png")
    else
        img.img-circle.headshot(src=$headshot)
```

Specifically `undefined variable $headshot`. It seems that `$headshot` does not exist within the scope of the `if` statement. This isn't the first time I've run into this behavior using this implementation and it's frustrating to try to work around. The trouble that it takes made me wonder, is there possibly a reason the language works this way?

Additionally, can anyone think of a way to work around the "feature" in this case? The best I can come up with is to change it later client-side with Javascript.

Comment: If you have a language-specific question, it's typically better to add a tag for that language. It brings it to the attention of those who monitor that tag, getting you help sooner from those who are knowledgeable. It also makes it available to future readers who are searching for language-specific information to find in a search. Can you [edit] and add one? You might make the title question appear less like asking for speculation or opinion; it usually helps as well.

Comment: I added tags for Go and Jade, but as far as I know the creators of Jade are unaffiliated with this project

Comment: Who said anything about affiliations? Your question is asking a (somewhat opinion seeking) question about the language design and how to deal with a situation, which others familiar with Go or Jade might be able to answer even if they're not the *creators of Jade*. Thanks for listening to half of what I said, anyway. :-)

Comment: Sounds like an implementation error. golang's if blocks can see their enclosing scope.

Comment: Wish there was an option to vote for "Convert to community approved answer" for these unanswered lonely questions. @Adam's comment would be such an example.

Comment: @mass Although I appreciate the support, my comment isn't an answer worth having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Go's `if` blocks have access to variables in their enclosing scope. If this is failing in your example, it must be because of an implementation error either in your code or the library you are using.

Next, let's fix some problems in the posted code:

```
each $headshot, index in $cause.Headshots
```

The order should be reversed--index goes first--and let's be consistent with the use of `$` to indicate variables:

```
each $i, $headshot in $cause.Headshots
```

With that cleared up, here is a full demo script:

#### templates/home.jade

```
html
    body
        each $i, $headshot in Cause.Headshots
            if $i == 0
                img.img-circle.headshot(src="/public/images/ellipse.png")
            else
                img.img-circle.headshot(src=$headshot)
```

#### demo.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-floki/jade"
)

func main() {
    w := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    // compile templates
    templates, err := jade.CompileDir("./templates", jade.DefaultDirOptions, jade.Options{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // then render some template
    tpl := templates["home"]
    tpl.Execute(w, map[string]interface{}{
        "Cause": map[string]interface{}{
            "Headshots": []string{"one", "two"},
        },
    })
    w.Flush()
}
```

This code works for me, the output is:

```
<html><body><img class="img-circle headshot" src="/public/images/ellipse.png" /><img class="img-circle headshot" src="two" /></body></html>
```

So my only conclusion is that there must be something else going on in your example. It could be a bug in the library, but I would first check the following things:

- is there a mixture of spaces and tabs in the jade file? This could cause scope confusion
- does the example I posted above also give you an error? If so,

  - are you using the latest version of the Jade library?
  - is your Go version up to date?

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! It appears the problem was that $index and $headshot were switched around. I think the error it was throwing, combined with the documentation for the node.js version (see the syntax here http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/ ) misled me.